# spring batch: inject main application context @Component using AutomaticJobRegistrar

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to inject some `@Service` / `@Repository` bean defined in main application context into some jobs loaded by `AutomaticJobRegistrar`.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.AutomaticJobRegistrar">
        <property name="applicationContextFactories">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.ClasspathXmlApplicationContextsFactoryBean">
                <property name="resources" value="classpath*:/META-INF/jobs/*Job.xml" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jobLoader">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultJobLoader">
                <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Using `@Autowired` inside my `ItemWriter` implementation class do not inject my services beans.

I have to enable component scanning inside each `*Job.xml` or declare each bean in order to make injection works, but injected classes are not the same instance of that one used by main application context.

How can I get the same instance bean declared in main application context?

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you activate `context:annotation-config` for each job?

If a new applicationcontext is created for every Job you need to activate this or no annotationprocessing (including @Autowired) will happen.

'context:component-scan' also activates 'context:annotation-config' so this might be the reason @Autowired works if you activate it.